Was the sons of God in the book of Genesis human or angel?
The problem with the sons of God being actual angels would mean that the angels are related to man. For in order to take the human female and mate with them, their genetic material must match ours. Still, there is also a problem with the Seth line taking human women and mating with them as well. Since man had already fallen, taking spouses would be the normal thing, so this is no news. Yet the author writes this as if it has more meaning then we know. It seems to be saying that these fallen angels were not to take human spouses, but they did anyways, and this caused a war between man. When God saw this, he had to put a stop to it, so he allowed a flood to happen which wiped out the problem, and only Noah survives along with his family.
But was the flood world wide? Scripture states the the Nephilim were on this world before the flood and after. So that would mean the flood was localized. Also, when scripture states that the flood covered the earth as well as the mountains, this can only mean that in the boundaries of Adams kin, the flood was massive in that area. And since the earth is still coming out of an ice age, there would be snow or ice in the higher elevations. Since snow and ice is water, one could include that as the area is being flooded.

Just as a courtesy advice please first take the time to read at least one, preferably upwards of ten other threads on this platform on the topic of sons of God being angels or humans in the OT before asking a redundant question that will be closed and removed. Thank you. Please familiarize yourself with the rules outlined for this particular stack in order to get the best experience and benefit the most from this community.

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I also recommend going through the Help Center's sections on both asking and answering questions.

Disagree that this question has already been answered elsewhere, as the other similar ones are not quite the same.  It should be left open.

https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8867/who-were-the-sons-of-god-bene-elohim-in-genesis-62
https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/19677/job16-who-are-the-sons-of-god

The other questions linked in the comments here are close, but they walk all around Gen. 6:2.  The question linked that comes the closest is from 10 yrs ago.  This is a much more explicit & recent question which deserves the opportunity to search the scripture more fully.

A few quick points:

angels are spiritual beings, but can take on physical form.
angels are not mortal and do not die


for they cannot even die anymore, for they are like angels, and are sons of God, being [a]sons of the resurrection. - Luke 20:36


though they can be imprisoned, which is what God created hell for.


Then He will also say to those on His left, 'Depart from Me, you accursed people, into the eternal fire which has been prepared for the devil and his angels...' - Matthew 25:41


Since they cannot die, and can go back to spiritual form, a global flood would not kill them. The flood killed their offspring, along with everyone else.
Because angels can choose what physical form they take, they don't need to be "genetically compatible" with humans, they simply temporarily take a form that is compatible.
Indeed Jude 6 tells us these angels were locked in hell because of their sexual interactions.


And angels who did not keep their own domain but abandoned their proper dwelling place, these He has kept in eternal restraints under darkness for the judgment of the great day, just as Sodom and Gomorrah and the cities around them, since they in the same way as these angels indulged in sexual perversion and went after strange flesh, are exhibited as an example in undergoing the punishment of eternal fire. - Jude 6-7

My interpretation:
I think of it like this: the devil, to control mankind pre-flood, told some of his fallen angels to do what God forbade and interbreed with mankind, so God imprisoned those angels, but the offspring were great warriors the devil could use to lord over and control tribes of people. They (the offspring) were wiped out in the flood.
Perhaps stories of this, past down post-flood, is where we get some myths like ancient debauched greek gods who come down and interbreed with mankind and produce "heroes" like Hercules or Achilles.
Seemingly, the devil even re-used this strategy post-flood (greek myths), wherein we also get Goliath and the other descendents of Anak, who are explicitly mentioned as descendents of the nephilim:

We saw the Nephilim there (the descendants of Anak come from the Nephilim). We seemed like grasshoppers in our own eyes, and we looked the same to them. - Numbers 13:33

This strategy is costly to the devil, though, as every time he has one of his angels do it, they get imprisoned permanently in hell by God for violating God's explicit commands. The devil doesn't himself get imprisoned, because he is careful not to violate God's commands himself.
Once nations got organized into real professional armies, this strategy became less beneficial, so not work sacrificing his angels. And indeed, in modern times, this strategy is all but useless.
Indeed, it is likely these angels (likely higher ranking ones) that satan sacrificed as pawns who God intentionally and temporarily releases out of prison in the end-times, in the 5th trumpet of Revelation 9:1-11.
Likely, satan told them that he'd win against God relatively quickly, and would release them, but they've been imprisoned now for thousands of years, and are probably angry it's taken so long.
By the time the 5th trumpet occurs, the first 4 trumpets have also occured:

God striking a third of the forests to burn
God striking a third of the oceans into blood
God striking a third of the fresh water into bitterness
God striking a third of the sky and stars with darkness

The fallen angels clearly see this as a sign from God telling them their time is up, God is winning. The "one-third"s are God reminding everyone how one-third of the angels rebelled, as God reminds us a few chapters later in Rev 12:4.
The fallen angels see the writing on the wall, so to speak, or rather, the writing on the sun, moon, stars, forests, oceans, and rivers. And the angels who followed satan's directions and ended up imprisoned for thousands of years now see it was for nothing, and satan is losing, and they are furious. So God lets them out for a short time, five months, purely to let them harass the humans who have allied with satan and taken the mark of the beast, or who are undecided. God forbids them from harming anyone who has God's mark on them.

Then out of the smoke came locusts upon the earth, and power was given them, as the scorpions of the earth have power. They were told not to hurt the grass of the earth, nor any green thing, nor any tree, but only the people who do not have the seal of God on their foreheads. And they were not permitted to kill anyone, but to torment for five months; and their torment was like the torment of a scorpion when it [d]stings a person. And in those days people will seek death and will not find it; they will long to die, and death will flee from them! Rev 9:3-6

This 5th trumpet's torment them up for 6th trumpet, where they call out to God for death, God grants it, which then means the population of the earth has shifted just enough, so the worship of the saints outweigh the worship of satan's kingdom, giving Jesus the authority to return and seize control of the earth in the 7th trumpet. The rapture, and the battle of armageddon, and more besides, take place over the next 30 days, including the 7 bowl judgements.
So what makes these fallen angels "sons of God"?
The bible reserves the term "sons of God" for those who God personally created, as a personal work of creation. All the angels (fallen or not) were personally created by God, and therefore are "sons of God". Adam and Eve were personally created, and therefore are also "sons of God". The rest of mankind is born from Adam and Eve, and therefore are "sons of Adam" or "sons of man". The children of Israel were, as a nation, created by God, so they are "children of God" collectively, but individually are not "sons of God". But Christian believers, having been saved, and "born again", not of flesh, but by God's Holy Spirit, are a new creation, personally created by God, so are individually "sons of God", like Adam, Eve, and the angels.

For all who are being led by the Spirit of God, these are sons of God. - Romans 8:14


For you are all sons of God through faith in Christ Jesus. - Galatians 3:26

Christ is a "son of God" (the Son of God; the only begotten one), but winkingly calls Himself the son of man, both to underline that He's actually come and been born of the flesh, born into humanity, like all of us, but also to reference Daniel 7:13, wherein someone like a son of man comes before The Lord YWHW God, and this human is given absolute authority and worship and power and called "The Highest One", which is so astounding to Daniel that he turns pale, and is greatly alarmed, that a "human" is elevated to the position of Godhood. (not realizing this human first was God, but did not consider Godhood something to be grasped, so lowered Himself a little lower than the angels, to be born of a man)

Have this attitude in yourselves which was also in Christ Jesus, who, as He already existed in the form of God, did not consider equality with God something to be grasped, but emptied Himself by taking the form of a bond-servant and being born in the likeness of men. Philippians 2:5-7

I think Daniel's vision in Daniel 7:13 is still in the future, and is actually at the end of the 30 days (or perhaps even 45 days later), after the battle of armageddon and the defeat of satan and the antichrist, because of the wording in Daniel 7:11-12.

A good point, that there is a difference between those directly created by God and those who are generated (by natural generation) by that which was directly created. The confusion of sons of God  taking daughters of men is thus highlighted that not only is there a difference of 'estate' but also a difference of origin.

The bible reserves the term "sons of God" for those who God personally created, as a personal work of creation this statement alone deserve extra points. This also nullifies the claim that humans born of women can be sons of God in the OT. It makes sense in the NT where after being born again by the Spirit of God they are new creatures and are now also sons of God but not prior to

This question has been discussed in several similar ways, but a strictly scriptural hermeneutical answer seems to evade most readers. So while Dottard has pointed out a similar question, it is not the same as the OP's.  All of scripture works together so that one scripture must balance with the others.  In the context of Gen. 6 the "sons of God" are earth born men.
The context of Gen. 6 follows immediately after the listing in Gen. 5 of the faithful line from Seth. These are the "sons of God" of Gen. 6:2.  Gen. 6:1 sets the context with "mankind," not hybrids of different species.

And it cometh to pass that mankind have begun to multiply on the face of the ground, and daughters have been born to them, (Gen. 6:1, YLT)

Gen 1:21-26 is the basis for the standard scientific biologic classification system  of genus and species where all living beings are multiplied on earth "after its kind."  Gen. 1:26 separates man and woman from the other living creatures as being made after God's image and God's likeness giving man dominion over all of the other living creatures.

And God saith, `Let Us make man in Our image, according to Our likeness, and let them rule over fish of the sea, and over fowl of the heavens, and over cattle, and over all the earth, and over every creeping thing that is creeping on the earth.' (YLT)

Gen. 6:4 is quite clear that the "sons of God" are not the same as the "fallen ones" in that verse.  They would not be called "sons of God" if they were the same as the "fallen ones."  If they were the same then they would be called "fallen ones" in both places in that one verse.

The fallen ones were in the earth in those days, and even afterwards when sons of God come in unto daughters of men, and they have borne to them -- they [are] the heroes, who, from of old, [are] the men of name. (Gen. 6:4, YLT)

Different words in the context of the chapter dealing with "mankind."  They were two different types of men - those who had fallen away from God, and those who followed after God.

for as many as are led by the Spirit of God, these are the sons of God; (Rom. 8:14, YLT)


For to which of the messengers said He ever, My Son thou art -- I to-day have begotten thee?' and again, I will be to him for a father, and he shall be to Me for a son?' (Heb. 1:5, YLT)

The word correctly translated as "messengers" in Heb. 1:5 is most often mistranslated as "angels."  So, to which angel did God ever call a son of God?
The entire premise of the fallen ones of Gen. 6:2 is based on false beliefs of pagan ideologies stemming from the 3rd - 1st centuries BC and the 1st-2nd centuries AD which have been continually misapplied to God's word.  The translations that use the Hebrew word "nephilim" in Gen. 6:4 are not translating it.  They are lifting it out of the Hebrew language and putting it into the English, transliterating it for sensational purposes.
The definition of the word "nephilim" is a giant, and means a feller, bully, or tyrant.  The old English word of "feller" commonly used for a rough, uncouth bully, from "faellan" or Saxon "fyllan" to make fall, cause to fall, strike down or kill (feller).
Excerpt from my post "Nephilim - Reprise: And the Sons of God" ShreddingTheVeil:
"There is then a sentence break beginning after verse 3.   That means that a new thought was begun in verse 4.   The word “giants” in the King James version is translated as “fallen ones” in Young’s, and is transliterated from the Hebrew in the NIV, and in many other versions as “nephilim”.    The words “after that” in verse 4 seem to be ignored by many readers.   The “giants”, or “fallen-ones”, or “nephilim” are not a result of “when the sons of God came in unto the daughters of men”.   They were already existing.
The word “giants” in the King James is questionable, as the correct translation is “fallen ones”.   As noted in my previous post titled “Nephilim.. Fallen Ones?”, Clarke’s commentary points out,
” It may be necessary to remark here that our translators have rendered seven different Hebrew words by the one term giants, viz., nephilim, gibborim, enachim, rephaim, emim, and zamzummim ; by which appellatives are probably meant in general persons of great knowledge, piety, courage, wickedness, etc., and not men of enormous stature, as is generally conjectured.”
Those translators who chose to use the Hebrew word “nephilim” in place of an English translation in Gen. 6:4 deliberately caused confusion for sensational speculation. Either way, the context of the Scriptures is mankind, and then specifically, the fallen of mankind.  Wicked and evil men.   Angels are not under discussion.
There is no basis for imagining that angels are fornicating with women on earth. Not only does Matt. 22:30 tell us that the physics of angels are different than those of mankind, but Genesis 1 sets the rules that science today teaches .. all species propagate or bear “after their kind”.  Genesis 5 reinforces the physics set by God as Adam, “… begat a son in his own likeness, and after his image; and called his name Seth:”  Gen. 5:3.   You cannot plant an orange seed, and get an apple tree!......
The “fallen ones” as correctly translated in Gen 6:4 in Young’s Literal Translation are the wicked and evil men under discussion as the entire subject matter of the first seven verses of Gen. 6, and are the reason that their wickedness grew throughout the world so that God repented that had He made man.  Those who followed after God were the sons of God, and they fell for the outward physical beauty of the daughters of unrighteous men.
The result was that God determined to wipe out the evil and wicked people on earth with the flood, saving only Noah and his wife, and his three sons, and their three wives..  along with most of the species of the rest of God’s creation… by twos, male and female, all which reproduce after their kind… as He gives instructions and is the subject matter of the rest of Chapter 6.
Angels are not referenced anywhere in Gen. 6, and therefore are not the “sons of God” spoken of in Gen. 6."
It is interesting that the same English translations that use "Nephilim" in Gen. 6:4 translate that same word more correctly as "giants" in Num. 13:33.  In Gen. 6:4 the giants already were in the land before the "sons of God" looked upon the daughters of men.
On a separate note, the use of the phrase "sons of God" in Job 1:6 and 38:7 in the English is not the best translation.  The context of Job 1:6 is speaking of the heavenly, celestial messengers (angels).
Benson's commentary at Job 1:6 has "The Targum says, Troops of angels, the LXX., Angels of God; the holy angels are called sons of God, (Job 38:7, and Daniel 3:25; Daniel 3:28,) because of their creation by God, their resemblance of him in power, dignity, and holiness, and their filial affection and obedience to him." (Biblehub)
The Cambridge Bible for Schools and Colleges explains the use of "sons of God" at Job 1:6 as "The angels are not called “sons of God” as if they had actually derived their nature from Him as a child from its father; nor in a less exact way, because though created they have received a nature similar to God’s, being spirits; nor yet as if on account of their stedfast holiness they had been adopted by grace into the family of God. These ideas are not found here. The name Elohim or sons (i. e. members of the race) of the Elohim is a name given directly to angels in contrast with men. The word means probably “powers,” “mights,” and the name is given to God and angels in common; He is the Elohim preeminently, they are Elohim in an inferior sense. The name describes their nature or standing in contrast to what is human; the name angels, that is, messengers, is descriptive of the duties which they fulfil. The same Beings are called “sons of Elîm,” Psalm 89:6 (“sons of the mighty”), and Psalm 29:1 (“ye mighty”), and there as here they stand in the temple or palace of the Lord, Psalm 29:9; Psalm 89:6-8."  (Ibid)
Context matters.  Job 1 speaks of the celestial messengers, the host of heaven coming before YHVH to report to Him.  Gen. 6 was speaking of the condition and deterioration of mankind into evil ways.  While it is true that the heavenly messengers have and do some times appear in the form of men, that does not mean they can change their nature to be able to procreate with women.  And, teaching that the celestial messengers literally fell out of heaven is from pagan theology which can be explored more in my blog posts:
Testing The Spirits - Part IV(a): Slandering Angels
Testing The Spirits - Part IV(b): Slandering Angels
The fallen ones of Gen. 6:2 were wicked, earth born human men and women.
